# How to adjust position of axis labels and ticklabels in 3D pgfplots automatically/dynamically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, axis

how can I adjust the position of the `axis label` **and** `ticklabels` automatically and dynamically in a `pgfplots`? Currently I am always shifting them by a specified distance in centimeters.
But on this way, I always have problems when changing the `height` and `width` of the plot.

Here are two minimal working examples from `Latex` with the results I am expecting.

It would be great if the solutions works **for all** `x`, `y` and `z axis`.

Thank you.

**First:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Hello,
            ylabel=Bye,
        ]
            \addplot3[
                surf,
                samples = 10,
            ]
            {y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Hello,
            ylabel=Bye,
            xlabel style = {xshift=3cm,yshift=6.2cm},
            xticklabel style = {xshift=2.5cm,yshift=5.5cm},
        ]
            \addplot3[
                surf,
                samples = 10,
            ]
            {y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the axis options:

- `xticklabel pos=right`
- `yticklabel pos=right`
- `zticklabel pos=right`

This MWE draws your second graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Hello,
            ylabel=Bye,
            xticklabel pos=right,
            %yticklabel pos=right,
            %zticklabel pos=right,
        ]
            \addplot3[
                surf,
                samples = 10,
            ]
            {y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```